# How do I make a more efficient color changer? VB.net

Tags: vb.net, button, timer

I am trying to make a more efficent button color changer for every 500ms. I don't want to make a ton of timers so I thought if I put a threading time in the tick it would work. NOPE. I failed that. My code just turns them all on at the same time.

Any help to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
Private Sub AnimateButtons_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AnimateButtons.Tick
        BTN1.BackColor = Color.Red
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        BTN2.BackColor = Color.Red
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        BTN3.BackColor = Color.Red
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        BTN4.BackColor = Color.Red
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        BTN5.BackColor = Color.Red
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        BTN6.BackColor = Color.Red
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    End Sub
```

Comment: i'm pretty sure there's a way to loop through buttons if they are in some kind of container...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have much information here but depending on which control you use, the timer will be running on the UI thread. This mean, the UI will update only when the "Tick" is finish. You'll need to set your timer to 500ms and change only one button on each tick. Something like this:

```
Dim buttonIndex As Integer = 1 ' Keep the value of which button to change

Private Sub AnimateButtons_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AnimateButtons.Tick
        If buttonIndex = 1 Then BTN1.BackColor = Color.Red
        If buttonIndex = 2 Then BTN2.BackColor = Color.Red
        If buttonIndex = 3 Then BTN3.BackColor = Color.Red
        If buttonIndex = 4 Then BTN4.BackColor = Color.Red
        If buttonIndex = 5 Then BTN5.BackColor = Color.Red
        If buttonIndex = 6 Then BTN6.BackColor = Color.Red

    End Sub
        buttonIndex += 1
```

Instead of having a global variable, you can initialize the index as static inside the method. I think this should work.

```
Private Sub AnimateButtons_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AnimateButtons.Tick
        Static buttonIndex As Integer = 1

        If buttonIndex = 1 Then BTN1.BackColor = Color.Red
        If buttonIndex = 2 Then BTN2.BackColor = Color.Red
        If buttonIndex = 3 Then BTN3.BackColor = Color.Red
        If buttonIndex = 4 Then BTN4.BackColor = Color.Red
        If buttonIndex = 5 Then BTN5.BackColor = Color.Red
        If buttonIndex = 6 Then BTN6.BackColor = Color.Red

        buttonIndex += 1
    End Sub
```

If course, there are "better" ways of doing this like using a list but I hope you get the general idea.

Comment: Thank you! This got me in the right direction. I am building a prototype so this will work for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

This randomly sets the backcolor of buttons

```
Private PRNG As New Random
Private AnimTask As Task
Private isClosing As New Threading.ManualResetEvent(False)
Private Sub AnimateButtons_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AnimateButtons.Tick
    AnimateButtons.Stop()
    AnimTask = Task.Run(Sub()
                            'random backcolor of these buttons
                            Dim btns() As Button = {BTN1, BTN2, BTN3}
                            'the colors
                            Dim bColors() As Color = {Color.Red, Color.LightYellow, Color.Yellow, Color.LightGreen, Color.LightBlue}

                            For Each b As Button In btns
                                Me.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                                   'pick random color
                                                   b.BackColor = bColors(PRNG.Next(bColors.Length))
                                               End Sub)
                                Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
                            Next
                            Me.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                               If isClosing.WaitOne(0) Then
                                                   Me.Close()
                                               Else
                                                   AnimateButtons.Start()
                                               End If
                                           End Sub)
                        End Sub)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If Not isClosing.WaitOne(0) Then
        isClosing.Set()
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```